# how to give model class as parameter in retrofit which contains list of objects,

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

```
{
        "cartItems":[
            {
                "product":"2",
                "productType":"3",
                "qty":"50",
                "unit":"BAGS"
            },
            {
                "product":"1",
                "productType":"2",
                "qty":"50",
                "unit":"BAGS"
            }
        ]
}
```

//This type of JSON have to give as a param, so please can anyone help to clear it out,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think.
You just need to make a model class first. Then create a post method to pass that model class in your request.

For example, in your case:

1. The Model class :

   ```
   public class CartModel {

    @SerializedName("cartItems")
    ArrayList<CartItemsModel> cartItems;

    public ArrayList<CartItemsModel> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(ArrayList<CartItemsModel> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    public static class CartItemsModel {
        @SerializedName("product")
        String product;

        @SerializedName("qty")
        int qty;

        @SerializedName("BAGS")
        String unit;

        public String getProduct() {
            return product;
        }

        public void setProduct(String product) {
            this.product = product;
        }

        public int getQty() {
            return qty;
        }

        public void setQty(int qty) {
            this.qty = qty;
        }

        public String getUnit() {
            return unit;
        }

        public void setUnit(String unit) {
            this.unit = unit;
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. API Interface :

   ```
    //This is just for understanding, your method can be different according to 
    //your API structure.

    @POST("your-api-link") // excluding the base URL
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<CartModel> getUserRegistration(@Body CartModel cartModel);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources to auto-generate model classes.

https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

This is kotlin:

```
data class CarItemList(
    @SerializedName("cartItems")
    val cartItems: List<CartItem>?
)

data class CartItem(
    @SerializedName("product")
    val product: String?,
    @SerializedName("productType")
    val productType: String?,
    @SerializedName("qty")
    val qty: String?,
    @SerializedName("unit")
    val unit: String?
)
```